# Using the import state in Node v14+ without adding the .js extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

In Node v12 I was using ESM imports by adding the following flags:

```
node --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```

This let me do the following:

```
import myFunc from "./lib/myFunc"
```

Now, in Node v14, we apparently no longer need the experimental-modules flag. However, when I run `node index.js` I get an error telling me that my imports need to `.js` extension like this:

```
import myFunc from "./lib/myFunc.js"
```

Is this the intended behaviour? If so, why have they suddenly added the need for the `.js` extension when previously it wasn't. The exact error I get is:

```
Cannot find module 'c:\xxx\lib\myFunc' imported from c:\xxx\index.js
Did you mean to import ../lib/myFunc.js?
```